# replacing one jpanel with another jpanel

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel

I want to replace the current panel and call another panel in `JPanel` forms.
I try to do using `setContentPane()` and `getContentPane()` method but it gives error.
how can I do that....
I also try this but clear all the componens but do not add anything

```
private void loginButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    try {
        if (new ConnectionFactory().userLoginCheck(usernameText.getText(), new String(passwordText.getPassword()))) {
            removeAll();   
            add(new ChangeUsernamePassword());
            revalidate();
            repaint();
             //new Welcomeboard();
        } else {
            warningLabel.setText("Invalid Username Or Password!!!");
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DashboardPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DashboardPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> "I want to replace the current panel and call another panel in JPanel forms"

Instead of trying to add an remove panels, use a `CardLayout`. Seeing how you're using Netbeans GUI Builder, see [How to Use CardLayout with Netbeans GUI Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21898439/2587435).  What the `CardLayout` does is allow you to change between different views without having to add and drop panels, which can be troublesome.

Also you may want to debug your if statement. Hard to tell with only the little but of code you're showing.