# I need to create a Jpanel Array but also use buttons to set the correct panel to visible when pressed

Tags: java, arrays, swing, netbeans, jpanel

This is the code i have for one button setting its corresponding Jpanel to visible and the other jpanels to false.

```
private void twickenhamButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    twickenhamPanel.setVisible(true);
    wembleyPanel.setVisible(false);
    ellandPanel.setVisible(false);
    sandyPanel.setVisible(false);
    mkPanel.setVisible(false);
    EtihadPanel.setVisible(false);
    villaParkPanel.setVisible(false);
    stJamesPanel.setVisible(false);
    millenniumPanel.setVisible(false);
    leicesterPanel.setVisible(false);
    kingsholmPanel.setVisible(false);
    OlympicPanel.setVisible(false);
}
```

But how to i add all of these jpanels to an array, but also use their corresponding buttons to set them to visible when clicked?

Comment: What you want is a generic solution for all your button implementation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of your code, it looks like you only want *one* panel to be visible at a time. This seems like a perfect use of a `CardLayout`, that will allow you to swap view. You can map a name to each panel.

```
private static final String TWICKENHAM = "twickenham";

CardLayout layout = new CardLayout();
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(layout);
mainPanel.add(twickenhamPanel, TWICKENHAM);
```

Then when you want to show the `twickenhamPanel`, you can just call `layout.show(mainPanel, TWICKENHAM)`.  It might all sound foreign to you, but you can learn more at [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Also by the method signature of your `actionPerformed`, it looks like you are using Netbeans GUI Builder. If that's the case, you may also want to look at [How to use CardLayout with Netbeans GUI Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21898439/2587435)