# How to add/remove a JPanel from a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm trying to set a variable to be a new `JPanel` and then add it once a button is pressed, but it is not working and I don't know why.

code:

```
private void nextButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    remove(scriptPanel);
    scriptPanel = new GemPanel();
    add(scriptPanel);
    validate();
    repaint();
    pack();
}
```

`GemPanel` is just a `JPanel` class I made. When I press the next button, it re-sizes the frame to be as small as possible and nothing actually happens. If I re-size it to normal, the original `scriptPanel` is still there.

What gives?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to remove and add entire panels, a better, less problem prone approach would be to use a `CardLayout` that will allow to swap views. You can see more at [How to use Cardlayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Also, by the looks of your method signature, it seems you're using the Netbeans builder too. You may also want to take a look at [How to Use CardLayout with Netbeans Gui Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21898439/2587435)

Comment: @user3527825 Um not really, IMO it's a lot much cleaner. Suit yourself though.

Comment: _"and it's hard to navigate through also."_ . Um `layout.show(panel, "card")` doesn't seem that hard to _me_

Comment: _"There has to be a way to get what I want to work"_. You need to provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @user3527825 CardLayout is the recommended method for typically achieving what you are trying to do...

Comment: +1, `it doesn't suit what I'm trying to do.` - it shows a different panel. Which is what you are trying to do. How does this not meet your requirement? `it's hard to navigate through` - it has built in next/previous methods as oppose to you writing your own. How is this hard to use? It also has a "show" method as oppose to writing your own. How is this hard to use? `There has to be a way to get what I want to work` - well you haven't actually stated a requirement that the CardLayout doesn't meet. You only posted a few lines of non-working code.