# Next and Previous Buttons Displaying Charts Malfunction

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jfreechart

I am trying to step through a `ArrayList<JPanel>` which contains `ChartPanels`. The `Next` button correctly steps through the charts as expected, but when I click the `Previous` button nothing happens. I feel like my logic may be convoluted. Thanks!

Note: `panelCombination` is a `JPanel`.

Code for the buttons:

```
public static int advance = 0;
public static ArrayList<JPanel> chartList = new ArrayList<>();

private void NextMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  

        panelCombination.removeAll();
        panelCombination.add(chartList.get(advance));
        panelCombination.validate();
        if (advance < chartList.size()-1) {
            advance++;
        }
}                                 

private void PreviousMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      

    if (advance > 0) {
         advance--;
    }
    panelCombination.removeAll();
    panelCombination.add(chartList.get(advance));
    panelCombination.validate();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `CardLayout` to change views, instead of trying to remove and add panels. What you're trying to do can easily be accomplished by calling the `next()` and `previous()` methods of the `CardLayout`. All you really need to do is set the layout of your `panelCombination` to `CardLayout`, add all you panels to the `panelCombination` and use those methods

```
CardLayout layout = new CardLayout();
panelCombination.setLayout(layout);
// add all panels.
....
private void PreviousMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) { 
    layout.previous(panelCombination);
```

See more at [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Also from the looks of you method signatures, it looks like you are using NetBeans GUI Builder. You can see [How to Use CardLayout with Netbeans GUI Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21898439/2587435)

Comment: Thank you very much, I will read up on CardLayouts; I was not even aware.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else has this issue in the future: the code that I used after reading through the javadoc and links peeskillet provided:

```
public class ResultsFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public static CardLayout switchPanels;  

/**
 * Creates new form ResultsFrame
 */
public ResultsFrame() {

    initComponents();
    switchPanels = new CardLayout();
    panelCombination.setLayout(switchPanels);
    getPDDGraph();
    //getProfileGraph();

}

private void NextMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt){                                     
   switchPanels.next(panelCombination);       
}                                 

private void PreviousMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
   switchPanels.previous(panelCombination);    
}              

 public static void getPDDGraph() {
   .....

     JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(xyplot);
     ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);

     panelCombination.add(chartPanel);
 }
```

Thanks again, it was much easier than what I was doing before and more condensed!