# netBeans GUI form change panel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, jpanel

I'm using the GUI form designer from netBeans for the first time and I just can't change the content of my JFrame.

What I want is to include an other JPanel when I get into a menu of my menu bar, so I tried like I was used to do when I wasn't using the GUI form designer.

My code :

```
 private void menuItemAddAssistActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
    Container container = this.getContentPane();
    container.removeAll();
    container.add(new PanelAddAssist());
    container.repaint();
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

I've look up for something that could help me but I'm just lost with this generated code. :/

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is use a `CardLayout` to switch between views, instead of trying to remove and add them. You can see [How to Use CardLayout with NetBean GUI Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21898439/2587435) for how to use it with the design tool. Also for the basics, see [How to Use CardLayout Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: Good to see the right answer offered first, and accepted.  :)