# How to Hide JPanel and Open another one in other Java FIle?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans-7

I'm newbie in java GUI , so i'm facing a problem right now ...
i've created a GUI using Netbeans GUI Builder ..
i've Created a file called MainUI.java and gdUI.Java
the MainUI.java contains the frame and buttons in which if a button is clicked the Jpanel Hides and opens the Panel from gdUI.java

here's the code i've done so far :

```
      private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        jPanel1.setVisible(false);


           }
```

and gdUI code is :

```
         package GUI;


         public class gdUI extends javax.swing.JPanel {

/**
 * Creates new form gdUI
 */
public gdUI() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 153, 51));
    setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(600, 500));
    setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(600, 500));
    setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(600, 500));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 600, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 500, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
// End of variables declaration
```

}

when i click the button , i successfully hided the current JPanel , how can i add the other files new one ?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: [`CardLayout`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/cardlayout/info) may be a suitable choice.

Answer (score 1):

The way you want to accomplish this task is using a `CardLayout` as pointed out by trashgod. This will allow you to switch between views, with simple `Cardayout` commands like `next()`, `previous()` and `show()`, the last allowing to show any particular component/view by name.

- You can see the Oracle tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)
- You can see [How to Use CardLayout with Netbeans GUI Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21898439/2587435)
- You can see how to drag and drop other panel forms [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22194357/2587435)