# How to get CardLayout implemented properly with Eclipse WindowBuilder?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, windowbuilder, cardlayout

So using WindowBuilder (latest version of Ecliple, Kepler) I've created a frame as so:
[image]

But I'd like to switch between them with a button, which I've created on the panelWelcome.
I'm guessing I'd add an itemListener, then create a method that switches between the cards. 
The problem is, I have no idea how to proceed after that. Here's the code that's automatically generated:

```
package client;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Test {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Test window = new Test();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Test() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));

        JPanel panelWelcome = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panelWelcome, "name_98933171901972");
        GridBagLayout gbl_panelWelcome = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_panelWelcome.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        gbl_panelWelcome.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        gbl_panelWelcome.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_panelWelcome.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        panelWelcome.setLayout(gbl_panelWelcome);

        JLabel lblTitle = new JLabel("MEMEPlayer");
        lblTitle.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.BOLD, 12));
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblTitle = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblTitle.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_lblTitle.gridx = 5;
        gbc_lblTitle.gridy = 0;
        panelWelcome.add(lblTitle, gbc_lblTitle);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Welcome! To get started, select a movie from the drop down menu");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblNewLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblNewLabel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_lblNewLabel.gridx = 5;
        gbc_lblNewLabel.gridy = 2;
        panelWelcome.add(lblNewLabel, gbc_lblNewLabel);

        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"The Avengers (2012)", "Monsters, Inc. (2001)", "Prometheus (2012)"}));
        GridBagConstraints gbc_comboBox = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_comboBox.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_comboBox.gridx = 5;
        gbc_comboBox.gridy = 4;
        panelWelcome.add(comboBox, gbc_comboBox);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Next >");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_btnNewButton = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_btnNewButton.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_btnNewButton.gridx = 5;
        gbc_btnNewButton.gridy = 6;
        btnNewButton.addItemListener((ItemListener) this);
        panelWelcome.add(btnNewButton, gbc_btnNewButton);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("");
        lblNewLabel_1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\temp\\Meme1\\largeVLC.png"));
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblNewLabel_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblNewLabel_1.gridx = 5;
        gbc_lblNewLabel_1.gridy = 8;
        panelWelcome.add(lblNewLabel_1, gbc_lblNewLabel_1);

        JPanel panelVideo = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panelVideo, "name_98968999152440");
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This doesnt answer ur question.. My advise to u is, dont use a code generator. Use a good layout manager like forms layout or mig layout. Ur layout code will be just a few lines and lot more easier to maintain than generated builder code. If u need links to good layout managers let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I see you're facing is that you are setting the layout to the frame. This is a problem because it means that the frame can only have *on* visible component at a time. *That* component being one of the panels. So you can put a button. The button would have to be on the one of the panels, which may be hard to maintain, in terms of navigation.

So instead, have a main `JPanel` that has the `CardLayout`, and add your card panels to *that* main panel. Then you can add the main panel to the frame, along with buttons for navigation.

Another option is to have a menu bar with option to change the cards, then that way, you can keep the card layout on the frame, because navigation is controlled by the menu options.

See [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) if you're not really sure even how to use CardLayout, hand coding. You're going to need a reference to layout and call one of its navigation methods like `show()`, `next()`, or `previous()`

You may also find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21898439/2587435) interesting. It used Netbeans, but maybe you'll pick something up