# CardLayout with netbeans using multiple external jpanel

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, cardlayout, gui-builder

i want use CardLayout in my JFrame form to swap JPanel
this is the code of JFrame form:

```
public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form Login
 */

public Login() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//
private void initComponents() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Login().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
// End of variables declaration
```

}

First JPanel to load when JFrame launch is:

```
public class LoginPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {
private Font original;

/**
 * Creates new form LoginPanel
 */



public LoginPanel() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    Email = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    emailField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    login = new javax.swing.JButton();
    password = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    passwordField = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
    register = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    background = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setLayout(null);

    Email.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    Email.setText("Email address");
    add(Email);
    Email.setBounds(155, 115, 90, 14);

    emailField.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            emailFieldMouseEntered(evt);
        }
        public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            emailFieldMouseExited(evt);
        }
    });
    add(emailField);
    emailField.setBounds(115, 135, 170, 20);

    login.setText("Login");
    add(login);
    login.setBounds(156, 240, 90, 23);

    password.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    password.setText("Password");
    add(password);
    password.setBounds(155, 170, 90, 14);
    add(passwordField);
    passwordField.setBounds(115, 191, 170, 20);

    register.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 255));
    register.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    register.setText("Don't have an account? Register!");
    register.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            registerMouseClicked(evt);
        }
        public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            registerMouseEntered(evt);
        }
        public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            registerMouseExited(evt);
        }
    });
    add(register);
    register.setBounds(115, 220, 170, 14);

    background.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Matteo\\Desktop\\Netbeans Project\\Social_Network\\background.png")); // NOI18N
    background.setText("jLabel1");
    add(background);
    background.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 300);
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void registerMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      

}                                     

private void registerMouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    original = register.getFont();
    Map attributes = original.getAttributes();
    attributes.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON);
    register.setFont(original.deriveFont(attributes));
    Cursor cursor = Cursor.getDefaultCursor();
    cursor = Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR);
    setCursor(cursor);
}                                     

private void registerMouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    register.setFont(original);
    Cursor cursor = Cursor.getDefaultCursor();
    setCursor(cursor);
}                                    

private void emailFieldMouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
    Cursor cursor = Cursor.getDefaultCursor();
    cursor = Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.TEXT_CURSOR);
    setCursor(cursor);
}                                       

private void emailFieldMouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
   Cursor cursor = Cursor.getDefaultCursor();
   setCursor(cursor);
}                                      


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel Email;
private javax.swing.JLabel background;
private javax.swing.JTextField emailField;
private javax.swing.JButton login;
private javax.swing.JLabel password;
private javax.swing.JPasswordField passwordField;
private javax.swing.JLabel register;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Second JPanel to swap when button clicked:

```
public class RegisterPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

/**
 * Creates new form RegisterPanel
 */
public RegisterPanel() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jPasswordField1 = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
    register = new javax.swing.JButton();
    cancel = new javax.swing.JButton();
    Name = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    LastName = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    Email = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    Password = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    icon = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jPasswordField2 = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
    repeatPassword = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setToolTipText("");
    setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(400, 300));
    setLayout(null);
    add(jTextField1);
    jTextField1.setBounds(110, 60, 240, 20);
    add(jTextField2);
    jTextField2.setBounds(110, 100, 240, 20);
    add(jTextField4);
    jTextField4.setBounds(110, 140, 240, 20);
    add(jPasswordField1);
    jPasswordField1.setBounds(110, 180, 240, 20);

    register.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Matteo\\Desktop\\Netbeans Project\\Social_Network\\cancel.png")); // NOI18N
    register.setText("Cancel");
    register.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            registerMouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });
    add(register);
    register.setBounds(240, 260, 90, 25);

    cancel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Matteo\\Desktop\\Netbeans Project\\Social_Network\\confirm.png")); // NOI18N
    cancel.setText("Register");
    add(cancel);
    cancel.setBounds(130, 260, 93, 25);

    Name.setText("Name");
    add(Name);
    Name.setBounds(20, 60, 27, 14);

    LastName.setText("Last name");
    add(LastName);
    LastName.setBounds(20, 100, 60, 14);

    Email.setText("Email address");
    add(Email);
    Email.setBounds(20, 140, 70, 14);

    Password.setText("Password");
    add(Password);
    Password.setBounds(20, 180, 50, 14);

    icon.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    icon.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Matteo\\Desktop\\Netbeans Project\\Social_Network\\addUser.png")); // NOI18N
    icon.setText("     Registration user");
    add(icon);
    icon.setBounds(20, 10, 180, 40);
    add(jPasswordField2);
    jPasswordField2.setBounds(110, 220, 240, 20);

    repeatPassword.setText("Repeat password");
    add(repeatPassword);
    repeatPassword.setBounds(20, 220, 90, 14);

    jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Matteo\\Desktop\\Netbeans Project\\Social_Network\\background.png")); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");
    add(jLabel1);
    jLabel1.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 300);
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void registerMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      

}                                     


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel Email;
private javax.swing.JLabel LastName;
private javax.swing.JLabel Name;
private javax.swing.JLabel Password;
private javax.swing.JButton cancel;
private javax.swing.JLabel icon;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField1;
private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField2;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
private javax.swing.JButton register;
private javax.swing.JLabel repeatPassword;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

How i need to write to swap JPanel when i click button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the `CardLayout` instance and use the `show(...)` of the layout, add pass it the name of the panel you want to show. This is all clearly stated in [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Also see [How to Use CardLayout with Netbeans GUI Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21898439/2587435) for

- how to set the names of the panels using the builder tool
- how to use the CardLayout in general with the bulder tool

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22194357/2587435) for

- how you can drag and drop your panels if you're having problems with that

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to call the `CardLayout` from inside your panels, you can create an interface to implement with a method to show. Have the class with the CardLayout implement it, and pass the instance of the frame to the panel Something like

```
public interface Switchable {
    void show(String card);
}

public class Login extends JFrame implements Switchable {
    LoginPanel panel = new LoginPanel(this);

    @Override
    public void show(String card) {
        CardLayout layout = (CardLayout)getLayout();
        layout.show(card);
    }
}

public class LoginPanel extends JPanel {
    private Switchable switcher;

    public LoginPanel(Switchable switcher) {
        this.switcher = switcher;
    }

    private void buttonActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        switcher.show(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does that matter? You eventually need to add the card panels to some other container, I'm guessing your frame class. From that class you instantiate the panels, give them names, then call show() using the name. Look through the links I posted. The last two in particular, for help with the builder tool. If you have a specific problem with implementing anything from the links, let me know what specifically you don't understand

Comment: See my update, maybe that helps, if the problem you are facing is that you want to access the cardlayout from the panel