# NetBeans inserts main() method in every added frame

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, gui-builder

When adding new class extending JFrame (or java.awt.Frame) the class is added with main() method inside like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewFrame5().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Every JFrame class has its own main method and I guess all classes starts simultaneously.

How do I add frames without main methods?

Comment: `NewFrame5()`  Choose a sensible name for classes.  The Netbeans suggestions are moronic.

Comment: thanks, that's just an example

Comment: It's an example of you creating `NewFrame1`, `NewFrame2`, `NewFrame3` **&** `NewFrame4`..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, see [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/2587435). Generally, recommended not to do it. See accepted answer for other possibilities (for example a JDialog)

As for your main concern, there's no way around netbeans creating the main method for top level containers like JFrame and JDialog. The logic seems right in the case of JFrame, as an application should only have one JFrame as the main top-level container for the application, but I'm not sure the logic behind the `JDialog` having a `main` method (as the dialog is usually run in the same JVM as the main JFrame). The only thing I can think is that the JDialog is created with a `main` for development purpopsed, if you want to test the dialog in stand-alone mode. But ultimately, you should delete the `main` method of the JDialog should you choose to use one.

Going back to the first point about multiple JFrames, other options I might recommend

- Use a JDialog. Yes you will have to delete the `main` method, when going into production, as the dialog will be instantiated within the context of the main JVM and generally shouldn't run its own process.
- Another option, depending on your requirements is to use a `Cardlayout` which will let you switch between views/panels (You can create JPanel forms in netbeans). See [How to Use CardLayout in Netbeans GUI Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21898425/how-to-use-cardlayout-with-netbeans-gui-builder/21898439#21898439) for a working guide. And the official [How to use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) tutorial

---

An aside, if you are a beginner, I strongly suggest you put aside the builder tool and learn to hand code first. There may be many tutorials teaching you how to use the builder tool, but they may miss out on important concept in the swing architecture and swing in general. IMO this will greatly affect your understanding of how and why things work with the builder, causing a lot a headache when trying to debug. Keep [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), the official tutorial handy and go through it.

Comment: +1 I've not tried it, but it might be possible to modify the template that generates the JFrame form or create your

Comment: @MadProgrammer  *"it might be possible to modify the template"* It sure is.  In fact, there is a comment at the top of every auto-generated class that describes how.  For my part, I added some new templates for a `JFrame` based and a `JOptionPane` based class, just because I detest being forced (by the default templates) to extend components when not adding functionality.

Comment: @AndrewThompson That's what I figured, but not having done it, didn't want to make an absolute statement ;)