# Cardlayout on jFrame with GridLayout on jPanels

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, cardlayout

I'm confused by how NetBeans handle layouts. I'm looking to implement a CardLayout that switches between several jPanels, on a jFrame. The jPanels have their own layouts (GridBagLayout). The first jPanel is a Login window, which after authentication would change to another jPanel, the main window. I have no clue where NetBeans generates the layout code as I can't find it.

Here is a picture of the structure I want:

[image: Structure]

Comment: Netbeans provides you auto-generation of code feature just to make sure you will sleep peacefully. On other node, if you need any help on real-code, please post the necessary code. P.S. CardLayout is most complex which share the same display place between 2 or more components.

Comment: The initialization and laying out of components is located in the `initComponents` (which is folded by default). It is not meant to be altered. If you need general help with using CardLayout with the builder tool, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21898439/2587435).

Comment: Thanks peeskillet! That link helped me greatly!