# Why my CardLayout .show() is not doing anything... Java Netbean

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, cardlayout

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
    CardLayout card = (CardLayout)main_panel.getLayout();
    card.show(main_panel, "jPanel1");
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    CardLayout card = (CardLayout)main_panel.getLayout();
    card.show(main_panel, "jPanel2");
}
```

hey guys I needed to use CardLayout to work with one of my existing project, but it never work! so I tried making a new form instead following the tutorial from [How to use CardLayout with Netbeans GUI Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21898425/how-to-use-cardlayout-with-netbeans-gui-builder) but I still can't get it to work... After clicking those buttons nothing will happen. Any help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
card.show(main_panel, "cardname");
```

you should pass card name not the variable name of sub panels in card layout. you have currently passed panels names  not card names.normally netbeans set card names as `card1,card2...`etc . you can see card name by selecting your sub panels[jpanel1,2..] from navigate and in the property window there is a row `cardname` in the layout category.

see this image

[image]

in this example (picture) you can see cardname is `card2` so if you want to show this selected button you should  use

```
card.show(main_panel, "card2");
```

but not

<strike>`card.show(main_panel, "jButton1");`</strike>

Comment: OMG THX SO MUCH! FINALLY!!!!! I'VE BEEN STUCK FOR 4 WHOLE HOUR......... sorry for my stupidity... THX SO MUCH Fast Snail!