# How to change JPanel after press button

Tags: java, swing

[image: Layout of my application]

I have a swing application that has a left side list of buttons and a panel at the right side, just like the gif. Depending on which button is clicked, a new panel should appear with some specific information. The code is entirely based on Netbeans 8.2 default GUI editor:

```
import java.awt.Color;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();     
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    panelControl = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    panelEncoder = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    lblEncoder = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    iconEncoder = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    panelRoute = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    lblRoute = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    iconRoute = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    panelLog = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    lblLog = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    iconLog = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    panelOrder = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    lblOrder = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    iconOrder = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    panelLogo = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);

    panelControl.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 59, 0));

    panelEncoder.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 59, 0));
    panelEncoder.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(208, 58));
    panelEncoder.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            panelEncoderMouseClicked(evt);
        }
        public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            panelEncoderMouseEntered(evt);
        }
        public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            panelEncoderMouseExited(evt);
        }
    });

    lblEncoder.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Ubuntu", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    lblEncoder.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    lblEncoder.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.LEFT);
    lblEncoder.setText("A");

    iconEncoder.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/icons8-mixer-de-configurações-vertical-32.png"))); // NOI18N

    javax.swing.GroupLayout panelEncoderLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panelEncoder);
    panelEncoder.setLayout(panelEncoderLayout);
    panelEncoderLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        panelEncoderLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(panelEncoderLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(iconEncoder)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(lblEncoder, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 29, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    panelEncoderLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        panelEncoderLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(panelEncoderLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(10, 10, 10)
            .addGroup(panelEncoderLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(lblEncoder, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 36, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(iconEncoder, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    panelRoute.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 59, 0));
    panelRoute.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            panelRouteMouseClicked(evt);
        }
        public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            panelRouteMouseEntered(evt);
        }
        public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            panelRouteMouseExited(evt);
        }
    });

    lblRoute.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Ubuntu", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    lblRoute.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    lblRoute.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.LEFT);
    lblRoute.setText("B");

    iconRoute.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/icons8-rota-32.png"))); // NOI18N

    javax.swing.GroupLayout panelRouteLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panelRoute);
    panelRoute.setLayout(panelRouteLayout);
    panelRouteLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        panelRouteLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(panelRouteLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(iconRoute)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(lblRoute, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    panelRouteLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        panelRouteLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(panelRouteLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(10, 10, 10)
            .addGroup(panelRouteLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(lblRoute, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(panelRouteLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(iconRoute)
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addGap(10, 10, 10))
    );

    panelLog.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 59, 0));
    panelLog.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            panelLogMouseClicked(evt);
        }
        public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            panelLogMouseEntered(evt);
        }
        public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            panelLogMouseExited(evt);
        }
    });

    lblLog.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Ubuntu", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    lblLog.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    lblLog.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.LEFT);
    lblLog.setText("D");

    iconLog.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/icons8-relatório-de-sistema-32.png"))); // NOI18N

    javax.swing.GroupLayout panelLogLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panelLog);
    panelLog.setLayout(panelLogLayout);
    panelLogLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        panelLogLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(panelLogLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(iconLog)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(lblLog, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    panelLogLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        panelLogLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(panelLogLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(10, 10, 10)
            .addGroup(panelLogLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(lblLog, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(iconLog, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    panelOrder.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 59, 0));
    panelOrder.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            panelOrderMouseClicked(evt);
        }
        public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            panelOrderMouseEntered(evt);
        }
        public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            panelOrderMouseExited(evt);
        }
    });

    lblOrder.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Ubuntu", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    lblOrder.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    lblOrder.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.LEFT);
    lblOrder.setText("C");

    iconOrder.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/icons8-lista-de-tarefas-32.png"))); // NOI18N

    javax.swing.GroupLayout panelOrderLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panelOrder);
    panelOrder.setLayout(panelOrderLayout);
    panelOrderLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        panelOrderLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(panelOrderLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(iconOrder)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(lblOrder)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    panelOrderLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        panelOrderLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(panelOrderLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(10, 10, 10)
            .addGroup(panelOrderLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(lblOrder, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(panelOrderLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(iconOrder)
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addGap(10, 10, 10))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout panelControlLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panelControl);
    panelControl.setLayout(panelControlLayout);
    panelControlLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        panelControlLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(panelEncoder, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 91, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addComponent(panelRoute, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addComponent(panelLog, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addComponent(panelOrder, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    panelControlLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        panelControlLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(panelControlLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(panelEncoder, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 57, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 0, 0)
            .addComponent(panelRoute, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 0, 0)
            .addComponent(panelOrder, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 0, 0)
            .addComponent(panelLog, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    panelLogo.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout panelLogoLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panelLogo);
    panelLogo.setLayout(panelLogoLayout);
    panelLogoLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        panelLogoLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    panelLogoLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        panelLogoLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("This panel should change depending on the icon I click");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(93, 93, 93)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addContainerGap(107, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(panelLogo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(panelControl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(panelLogo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 0, 0)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(panelControl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
    );

    getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("SparkAG\n");

    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void panelOrderMouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
    this.panelOrder.setBackground(new Color(255, 59, 0));
}                                      

private void panelOrderMouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
    this.panelOrder.setBackground(new Color(255, 106, 0));
}                                       

private void panelOrderMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
    /*SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()
        -> JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Type here: "));*/
    this.panelOrder.setBackground(new Color(255, 59, 0));
}                                       

private void panelLogMouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    this.panelLog.setBackground(new Color(255, 59, 0));
}                                    

private void panelLogMouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    this.panelLog.setBackground(new Color(255, 106, 0));
}                                     

private void panelLogMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    /*SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() ->
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Type here: "));*/
    this.panelLog.setBackground(new Color(255, 59, 0));       
}                                     

private void panelRouteMouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
    this.panelRoute.setBackground(new Color(255, 59, 0));
}                                      

private void panelRouteMouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
    this.panelRoute.setBackground(new Color(255, 106, 0));
}                                       

private void panelRouteMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
    /*SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() ->
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Type here: "));*/
    this.panelRoute.setBackground(new Color(255, 59, 0));          
}                                       

private void panelEncoderMouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
    this.panelEncoder.setBackground(new Color(255, 59, 0));
}                                        

private void panelEncoderMouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
    this.panelEncoder.setBackground(new Color(255, 106, 0));
}                                         

private void panelEncoderMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
    /*SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() ->
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Type here: "));*/
    this.panelEncoder.setBackground(new Color(255, 59, 0));               
}                                         

public static void main(String args[]) {  
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel iconEncoder;
private javax.swing.JLabel iconLog;
private javax.swing.JLabel iconOrder;
private javax.swing.JLabel iconRoute;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblEncoder;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblLog;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblOrder;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblRoute;
private javax.swing.JPanel panelControl;
private javax.swing.JPanel panelEncoder;
private javax.swing.JPanel panelLog;
private javax.swing.JPanel panelLogo;
private javax.swing.JPanel panelOrder;
private javax.swing.JPanel panelRoute;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

What should I do to display a different panel depending the button I click?

Comment: Use a `CardLayout`. It allows you to swap panels. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: ^---- Yes, yes, yes

Comment: Thanks @camickr, it worked perfectly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21898439/2587435